# Reference cell in another sheet with range not working

Tags: excel

I am referencing the value of a cell based on another value of other cell in another sheet. It works for the first row but once I go to the next row it doesn't work as it gets another value not the value I want. I feel it has something to do with the referecing using the RC way and the -ve values. Any advice?

=IF(RC[-1]="A";Predefined_data!RC[-1];IF(RC[-1]="B";Predefined_data!R[1]C[-1];IF(RC[-1]="C";Predefined_data!R[2]C[-1])))

The problem as soon as I try to lock the references like this:

The problem as soon as I try to lock the refeences and make them

```
=IF(RC[-1]="A";Predefined_data!R[2]C[1];IF(RC[-1]="B";Predefined_data!R[3]C[1];IF(RC[-1]="C";Predefined_data!R[4]C[1])))
```

It changes back to be using the referencing to the current cell not the fixed one I mentioned and reverts to:

```
=IF(RC[-1]="A";Predefined_data!RC[-1];IF(RC[-1]="B";Predefined_data!R[1]C[-1];IF(RC[-1]="C";Predefined_data!R[2]C[-1])))
```

Any advice?

Comment: You need to clarify the question. What exactly do you want when you "go to the next row"? What do you mean by "go to the next row", is it copying down the formula? An example of desired result would be helpful.

Comment: @ZygD Kindly find a link with an example here https://www.dropbox.com/s/kvccr5on5xzimkb/Test.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: The link should be : https://www.dropbox.com/s/kvccr5on5xzimkb/Test.xlsx?dl=1 || Upon opening the file, the formula in C2 shows : `=IF(A2="A",Predefined_data!A2,IF(A2="B",Predefined_data!A3,IF(A2="C",Predefined_data!A4)))` in my pc. || If you intend to lock the references.. `=IF(A2="A",Predefined_data!$A$2,IF(A2="B",Predefined_data!$A$3,IF(A2="C",Predefined_data!$A$4)))` (and drag downwards) should do. || Please correct/update the question to reflect the "A" in the sample file instead of "A1".

Comment: @p._phidot_ I've edited my question. For some reason I cannot lock the values, once I enter the Row and Column value of the referenced cell in the other worksheet it turns to the current worksheet cell referencing

Comment: I cannot reproduce your case (the formula in the question), as my referencing is not RC . Thus, I'm sharing the solution on how it was shown in screen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the ref : [Authoritative Excel range syntax reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977919/authoritative-excel-range-syntax-reference/47933697#47933697)

Just remove the block bracket, replace it with the cell exact location value and the referencing will be absolute.. (functions the same as $ symbol as per comment.)

So the solution should be :
`=IF(RC[-1]="A",Predefined_data!R2C1,IF(RC[-1]="B",Predefined_data!R3C1,IF(RC[-1]="C",Predefined_data!R4C1)))`

Hope it solves. ( :